# Finding an unknown coordinate

Tags: geometry

[image]

ADE is a straight line .
AE : AD = 3 : 2 
Find coordinates of E

My workings

Let E ( X , Y)

Gradient AD = Gradient of AE
$ 1/3 = X - 3 / Y - 1 $

From here I'm not too sure on how to carry on.. Can I have a hint ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be the coordinates of $E$. As $AE:AD=3:2$ so$${Y-1\over 3-1}={X-(-3)\over 3-(-3)}={3\over 2}$$
$(X,Y)=(6,4)$

Done!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The gradient of $AD$ also equals the gradient of $DE$.

Continue your working with this hint. Hope this helps.